# Capture file existance status and send output to csv file in ansible

Tags: azure, ansible

Here is Ansible playbook to check the config file exist and capture that output using register and send that output to csv file.If file exist It should get 1 in csv file.But am getting error "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was : 'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout' \n\n The error appeares to be in ..../..../../main.yml , but may \n be elsewhere in the file depending n the exact syntax problem. \n \n The offending line appears to be \n\n\n"

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name : Gather the metadata
    shell : curl -H Metadata:true "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance"  
    register : vm_medtadata

  - name : Assign the meta json to variable
    set_facts:
      meta : "{{vm_metadata.stdout }}" 

  - name : setting the facts for csv
    set_fact:
      vm_resourcegroup: "{{meta.compute.resourceGroupName }}"

  - name : check config file exist
    stat:
      path: /etc/example.config
      register: file_status

  - name: create local file with file existance status 
    local_action : copy content = "{{vm_resourcegroup}} {{ansible_hostname}}  {{file_status.stdout}}" \n dest= "{{build_source_dir}}/src/ansible/ansible_file_status{{anisible_hostname}}.csv "
...
```

Comment: Update the question with the output of `- debug: var=vm_medtadata`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> local_action: copy content = "{{vm_resourcegroup}} {{ansible_hostname}}  {{file_status.stdout}}" \n dest= "{{build_source_dir}}/src/ansible/ansible_file_status{{anisible_hostname}}.csv "

You have a misunderstanding about `stat:` -- it does not have a `.stdout` property, but rather an `.stat` property [with several sub-fields](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/stat_module.html#return-values)

Also, your local_action appears to have a stray `\n` in it, perhaps you meant to include that inside the double-quotes?